# New background highlighting of code?

Tags: discussion, design

Is there a new (e.g. grayish) background highlighting for code now? I get the impression that there is and that syntax highlighting does not stand out as well against it as it stood out before.  I mean what you get by doing, say, this:

```
<!-- language: lang-el -->
```

Comment: I haven't noticed a recent change. Code blocks have always had a gray background and I'm not aware that the shade has changed. But there is going to be a major design change very soon anyway: https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/emacs-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing

Comment: 1. OK. Seems like the blue of `defun` doesn't show up well. 2. Guess we'll have to address problems introduced by the new design after it descends upon us. 3. Was such a new design actually *requested* by users, or is this just some top-down imposed "improvement"?

Comment: The new design is imposed. Its primary motivation is to make it easier for Stack Exchange to design ultra-lightweight themes for new sites, and to evolve site designs. The two benefits for users is that it's a first step towards responsive design, and that sites that still have the beta look can get a custom design faster. User reception on sites that have switched has ranged from [unenthusiastic](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13242) to [anger](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4923) to [hatred](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7781).

Comment: @Gilles: I see. So this is done to benefit users, but so far the available existing-user response is negative. Interesting summary. ;-) Yes, I saw some similar reactions in English Language & Usage. Whatever happened to "poll the users"?

Comment: This is not really done to benefit the users, no. It has only one advantage for users of sites that already have their own design, which is responsiveness, and even for that many users don't care and the feature is still very far from working properly. SE polled the users, users said “this sucks”, SE said “tough”.

Comment: @Gilles: OK. Thanks for the background. Not a big deal, but too bad, I guess (aka "tough").